# How to convert a workbook object into an output stream in python

Tags: python, excel, azure-functions, outputstream

I want to convert a workbook object (<openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook object  0x00000150265A6B80>) into an Output stream using python.

this is my python code.

```
def main(inputblob: func.InputStream, outputblob: func.Out[BytesIO]):
logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
             f"Name: {inputblob.name}\n"
             f"file: {inputblob}\n"
             f"Blob Size: {inputblob.length} bytes")

    ...some code goes here...

today = date.today()
date_today = today.strftime("%m-%d-%y")
outputfile = "{}_COMPLETE_{}".format(date_today,input_file_name)

wb.save(outputfile)
output = BytesIO(wb)

outputblob.set(output)
```

This gives an error.

> Executed 'Functions.BlobTrigger' (Failed, Id=291563d2-407c-4540-9471-9f49cbc74857, Duration=77564ms)
> [2023-03-30T06:42:20.778Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.BlobTrigger. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
> Exception: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Workbook'
> Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 452, in _handle__invocation_request
> call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor(
> File "C:\Users\Asuni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
> result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
> File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 718, in
> _run_sync_func
> return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context,
> File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\extension.py", line 215, in *raw_invocation_wrapper
> result = function(**args)
> File "D:\Automization of Invoice Compare\Service Projects-1\Customers\InvoiceCompare\BlobTrigger_*init**.py", line 368, in main
> output = BytesIO(wb)

I tried various things like converting my workbook into BytesIO, StringIO objects.But any of those did not work.

Can someone please help me?

PS:
**My full code**

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import pandas as pd
import os,io
from azure.data.tables import TableServiceClient
#from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, 
ContainerClient
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Border, Side, Alignment, 
Protection, Font
from datetime import date
from io import BytesIO,StringIO


def main(inputblob: func.InputStream, outputblob: 
func.Out[StringIO]):
logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
             f"Name: {inputblob.name}\n"
             f"file: {inputblob}\n"
             f"Blob Size: {inputblob.length} bytes")
 
# Set up the connection to the Azure Table storage account
connection_string = 
'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;'

table_service_client = 
TableServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

# Create the BlobServiceClient object
#blob_service_client = 
BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

# Get a reference to the table
table_name = 'runtimedocument'
table_client_document = 
table_service_client.get_table_client(table_name)

# Get a reference to the blob container
#container_name = 'cloudops-resources/inputs' 

# Get a reference to the blob
#blob_client_instance = 
blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container_name, inputblob, 
snapshot=None)

# Instantiate a ContainerClient
#container_client = 
blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

# Query the entities in runtimedocument table
INOs_from_runtimedocument = 
list(table_client_document.list_entities(select=["InvoiceNo"]))
Status_from_runtimedocument = 
list(table_client_document.list_entities(select=["Status"]))

INOs_from_runtimedocument_list = []
for x in range(len(INOs_from_runtimedocument)):
    
INOs_from_runtimedocument_list.append(INOs_from_runtimedocument[x] 
["InvoiceNo"])

Status_from_runtimedocument_list = []
for y in range(len(Status_from_runtimedocument)):
   
Status_from_runtimedocument_list.append(Status_from_runtimedocument[y]["Status"]) 
                                                                        

# Query the entities in runtimeedi table
runtimeedi = ['100302308549','100302308550','100302308551','100302308552','100302308553','100302308554','100302308555','100302308556',
            '100302308557','100302308558','100302308559','100302308560']

# Query the entities in runtimeemail table
runtimeemail = ['100302308552','100302308553','100302308554','100302308555','100302308556','100302308557','100302308558','100302308559',
            '100302308560','100302308561','100302308562','100302308563']

# Query the entities in runtimefile table
runtimefile = ['100302308557','100302308558','100302308559','100302308560','100302308561','100302308562','100302308563','100302308564',
            '100302308565','100302308566','100302308567','100302308568']

# Query the entities in runtimeprint table
runtimelocalprint = ['100302308567','100302308568','100302308569','100302308570','100302308571','100302308572','100302308573','100302308574',
                    '100302308575','100302308576','100302308577','100302308578']

    
# List the blobs in the container
'''blob_list = container_client.list_blobs(prefix="inputs/")
for blob in blob_list:
    input_file_name = (blob.name[7:])'''

#blobstring = blob_service_client.get_blob_to_text("cloudops- 
resources/inputs",inputblob).content
#Reading the input xlsx file from customer
#df0 = pd.read_excel(StringIO(blobstring))

#book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=inputblob.read())
#df0 = openpyxl.load_workbook(inputblob)
df0 = pd.read_excel(inputblob.read())
logging.info(f"{df0}")

#Opening a new workbook and a worksheet
wb = Workbook()
sheet = wb.active

#Defining column width
sheet.column_dimensions['A'].width = 20
sheet.column_dimensions['B'].width = 15
sheet.column_dimensions['C'].width = 10
sheet.column_dimensions['D'].width = 10
sheet.column_dimensions['E'].width = 10
sheet.column_dimensions['F'].width = 10
sheet.column_dimensions['G'].width = 10
sheet.column_dimensions['H'].width = 22
sheet.column_dimensions['I'].width = 19
sheet.column_dimensions['J'].width = 19
sheet.column_dimensions['K'].width = 19
sheet.column_dimensions['L'].width = 19
sheet.column_dimensions['M'].width = 19

# Add a header format.
font1 = Font(name='Calibri',size=11,bold=True)
font2 = Font(name='Calibri',size=11,bold=False)

fill = PatternFill(start_color='ECC4A0',
                end_color='ECC4A0',
                fill_type='solid')

border = Border(
        left=Side(border_style='thin', color='00000000'),
        right=Side(border_style='thin', color='00000000'),
        top=Side(border_style='thin', color='00000000'),
        bottom=Side(border_style='thin', color='00000000'))

alignment=Alignment(horizontal='center',
                    vertical='center',
                    wrap_text=True,
                    shrink_to_fit=True)
                    

protection = Protection(locked=True,
                        hidden=False)

#Adding column headers
hA = sheet['A1']
hB = sheet['B1']
hC = sheet['C1']
hD = sheet['D1']
hE = sheet['E1']
hF = sheet['F1']
hG = sheet['G1']
hH = sheet['H1']
hI = sheet['I1']
hJ = sheet['J1']
hK = sheet['K1']
hL = sheet['L1']
hM = sheet['M1']

hA.value = "InvNo"
hA.font = font1
hA.border = border
hA.alignment = alignment
hA.protection = protection

hB.value = "Payer"
hB.font = font1
hB.border = border
hB.alignment = alignment
hB.protection = protection

hC.value = "Document"
hC.font = font1
hC.border = border
hC.alignment = alignment
hC.protection = protection

hD.value = "EDI"
hD.font = font1
hD.border = border
hD.alignment = alignment
hD.protection = protection

hE.value = "E-mail"
hE.font = font1
hE.border = border
hE.alignment = alignment
hE.protection = protection

hF.value = "File"
hF.font = font1
hF.border = border
hF.alignment = alignment
hF.protection = protection

hG.value = "Print"
hG.font = font1
hG.border = border
hG.alignment = alignment
hG.protection = protection

hH.value = "Check Invoice"
hH.font = font1
hH.border = border
hH.alignment = alignment
hH.protection = protection

hI.value = "runtimedocument status"
hI.font = font2
hI.fill = fill
hI.border = border
hI.alignment = alignment
hI.protection = protection

hJ.value = "runtimeedi status"
hJ.font = font2
hJ.fill = fill
hJ.border = border
hJ.alignment = alignment
hJ.protection = protection

hK.value = "runtimeemail status"
hK.font = font2
hK.fill = fill
hK.border = border
hK.alignment = alignment
hK.protection = protection

hL.value = "runtimefile status"
hL.font = font2
hL.fill = fill
hL.border = border
hL.alignment = alignment
hL.protection = protection

hM.value = "runtimelocalprint status"
hM.font = font2
hM.fill = fill
hM.border = border
hM.alignment = alignment
hM.protection = protection

greenfill = PatternFill(start_color='C0FED5' , end_color='C0FED5', 
fill_type='solid')
yellowfill = PatternFill(start_color='FDF4BB' , end_color='FDF4BB', 
fill_type='solid')
redfill = PatternFill(start_color='CD362F' , end_color='CD362F', 
fill_type='solid')
pinkfill = PatternFill(start_color='FEB9CF' , end_color='FEB9CF', 
fill_type='solid')

#Iterating through every row 
invoice_no_list = []
payer_list = []
length = (len(df0))

for i in range(len(df0)):

    div = df0.at[i, 'Div']
    inv = df0.at[i, 'Inv no']

    div_str = str(div)
    inv_str = str(inv)

    #concatanating division and invoice no from the input file
    Invoice_No = div_str + inv_str
    invoice_no_list.append(Invoice_No)
    cellNo_InvoiceNo = "A"+str(i+2)
    A = sheet[cellNo_InvoiceNo]
    A.value = Invoice_No

    #Slicing the " ' " in the payer column
    payer = df0.at[i,'Payer']
    payer_modified = payer[1:] 
    payer_list.append(payer_modified)
    cellNo_payer = "B"+str(i+2)
    B = sheet[cellNo_payer]
    B.value = payer_modified

    #Checking whether the Invoice nos are in runtimedocument
    cellNo_document_existence = "C"+str(i+2)
    C = sheet[cellNo_document_existence]
    C.border = border
    if Invoice_No in INOs_from_runtimedocument_list:
        C.value = "Exists"
        C.fill = greenfill
    else:
        C.value = "N/A"
        C.fill = yellowfill

    #Finding Index Positions of duplicate invoice numbers in 
    runtimedocument
    def find_indices(INOs_from_runtimedocument_list, Invoice_No):
        indices = []
        for idx, value in 
        enumerate(INOs_from_runtimedocument_list):
            if value == Invoice_No:
                indices.append(idx)
        return indices
        
    duplicates = find_indices(INOs_from_runtimedocument_list, 
    Invoice_No)
    
    cellNo_status_document = "I"+str(i+2)
    I = sheet[cellNo_status_document]
    I.border = border
    I.alignment = alignment

    #printing error status of relevant invoice numbers in 
    runtimedocument
    for d in duplicates:
        if(Status_from_runtimedocument_list[d]=="error"):
            I.value = "error"
            I.fill = pinkfill
        else:
            pass

    #printing ok status in the remaining cells in runtimedocument
    if (i <= length):
        if (I.value == None):
            I.value = "ok"
            I.fill = greenfill
        else:
            pass


    #Checking whether the Invoice nos are in runtimeedi
    cellNo_edi_existence = "D"+str(i+2)
    D = sheet[cellNo_edi_existence]
    D.border = border
    if Invoice_No in runtimeedi:
        D.value = "Exists"
        D.fill = greenfill
    else:
        D.value = "N/A"
        D.fill = yellowfill

    #Checking whether the Invoice nos are in runtimeemail
    cellNo_email_existence = "E"+str(i+2)
    E = sheet[cellNo_email_existence]
    E.border = border
    if Invoice_No in runtimeemail:
        E.value = "Exists"
        E.fill = greenfill
    else:
        E.value = "N/A"
        E.fill = yellowfill

    #Checking whether the Invoice nos are in runtimefile
    cellNo_file_existence = "F"+str(i+2)
    F = sheet[cellNo_file_existence]
    F.border = border
    if Invoice_No in runtimefile:
        F.value = "Exists"
        F.fill = greenfill
    else:
        F.value = "N/A"
        F.fill = yellowfill

    #Checking whether the Invoice nos are in runtimelocalprint
    cellNo_localprint_existence = "G"+str(i+2)
    G = sheet[cellNo_localprint_existence]
    G.border = border
    if Invoice_No in runtimelocalprint:
        G.value = "Exists"
        G.fill = greenfill
    else:
        G.value = "N/A"
        G.fill = yellowfill

    if (i<=length):
        cellNo_Check_Invoice = "H"+str(i+2)
        H = sheet[cellNo_Check_Invoice]
        H.border = border
        if(D.value == "N/A" and E.value == "N/A" and G.value == 
        "N/A"):
            H.value = "Investigation needed"
            H.fill = redfill
        elif(D.value == "Exists" and E.value == "N/A" and G.value 
        == "N/A" and I.value == "error"):
            H.value = "Investigation needed"
            H.fill = redfill
        elif(D.value == "Exists" and E.value == "N/A" and G.value 
        == "N/A" and I.value == "ok"):
            H.value = "Investigation not needed"
            H.fill = greenfill
        else:
            pass

#Saving the file
#input = os.path.basename(inputblob.name)
today = date.today()
date_today = today.strftime("%m-%d-%y")
outputfile = "{}_COMPLETE_{}".format(date_today,inputblob.name)
wb.save(outputfile)

#Converting output file into a StringIO object
output = StringIO.__str__(wb)
out = StringIO(output)

outputblob.set(out)
'''logging.info(f"Name: {outputblob.name}\n"
             f"file: {outputblob}\n"
             f"Blob Size: {outputblob.length} bytes")'''
```

Here, I have converted the workbook object into StringIO.I want to place this output file in a blob container in azure storage explorer.
I want the file as an Output stream.

**My current code for saving the file in the blob container.**

```
#Saving the file
input = os.path.basename(inputblob.name)
today = date.today()
date_today = today.strftime("%m-%d-%y")
outputfile = "{}_COMPLETE_{}".format(date_today,input)

cc = "http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/cloudops- 
resources/outputs/"+ outputfile
wk = openpyxl.load_workbook(cc)
o = io.BytesIO()
wk.save(o)
data= o.getvalue()
print(data)
```

but it gives this error.

> Exception: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/cloudops-resources/outputs/03-30-23_COMPLETE_Input_file456.xlsx'

I tried this as well.

```
#Saving the file
input = os.path.basename(inputblob.name)
today = date.today()
date_today = today.strftime("%m-%d-%y")
outputfile = "{}_COMPLETE_{}".format(date_today,input)
wb.save("template.xlsx")



with NamedTemporaryFile() as outputfile:
    wb.save(outputfile.name)
    outputfile.seek(0)
    stream = outputfile.read()

outputblob.set(data)
```

But, it gives this error.

> Exception: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\Asu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp06vytpds'

Comment: can you provide full code? What are passing as input_file_name

Comment: I will update my current code in the question.That was the code I tried converting workbook into the StringIO

Comment: It is saying that you donot have permissions, try to get access first

Comment: How do I get permission for that?

Answer (score 0):

> How to convert a workbook object into an output stream in python

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and I followed [Document](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html):

```
import io
import openpyxl


outputfile= "/dbfs/FileStore/shared_uploads/v-bojja/file_example_XLSX_10-1.xlsx"
wk = openpyxl.load_workbook(outputfile)
o = io.BytesIO()
wk.save(o)
data= o.getvalue()
print(data)
```

you can keep outputfile as your output file.

**Output:**

[image]

Here the code you need to change is:

```
 wk = openpyxl.load_workbook(outputfile)
 o = io.BytesIO()
 wk.save(o)
 data= o.getvalue()
 print(data)
```

Output:

[image]

In my case I have hardcoded outputfile xlsx from location .

In your code you are directly giving output file, firstly you need to load into workbook using `openpyxl.load_workbook(outputfile)`

Comment: thank you. but here, "outputfile' variable is just the name I want to assign to the output file.It's content are in 'wb' variable. So, I wrote as follows.                                               
 wk = openpyxl.load_workbook(wb)
    outputfile = io.BytesIO()
    wk.save(outputfile)
    data= outputfile.getvalue()
    print(data)                                                                                                                                      
 But it gives an error. "Exception: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Workbook"

Comment: Have done the samething but got output and shared it too.Your error messages says that it needs a string or bytes but recieving webhook

Comment: I think something is wrong defining the path in my code.I will upload it in the above question.Can u pls have a look?

Comment: ok ill look into that once

Comment: thanks a lot.I included another solution I tried as well.Pls have a look